# Could not convert string to float: b'\xe7,F\xc0\xf5\x94PI'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, trending

I am trying to convert this string b'\xe7,F\xc0\xf5\x94PI' into float. Is there any method to do it?

Comment: what value it should give? How did you create it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you explain **what** are you trying to convert the string to? an example?